# How can I match an exact word within a string that is surrounded by whitespaces?

Tags: string, bash

I am trying to match a specific command using regex based on a set of allowed commands.

**This is the outcome I want to achieve:**

```sh
foo --happy-cat run meow # valid command
foo --happy-cat test meow # valid command
foo --happy-cat run-away woof # invalid command
```

**This is what I have tried to do**

```sh
case $* in
  (*run* | *test* | *build*) echo yes ;;
  *) echo no ;;
esac
```

**What's not working**
My match falsely matches `run-away` as a valid command. I only want to match `run`, `test` or `build` surrounded by whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to match spaces around given words like this:

```sh
case "$*" in
  *" run "*|*" test "*|*" build "*) echo yes ;;
  *) echo no ;;
esac
```

Also this is called glob matching not regular expressions.

Above script will match `" run "` and print `yes`, however for `run-away` it will not match first set of globs and will print `no`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to anubhava's answer, if you wanted to use actual regex you could do this:

```
s='foo --happy-cat run-away woof'  # test string
regex='\s+((run)|(test)|(build))\s+'

if [[ $s =~ $regex ]]
then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

This has the advantage of matching whitespace that isn't just space, but also tabs.